# Insert filename in files by using batch

Tags: batch-file

I am new in Batch coding, please help me in this, I am trying to write a batch file which can remove all words after 10 digits of every lines and after 10 digits insert the file name in .txt or .csv file without extension. but i can't get the right code.

My file is like that in below

Filename - `1234567.txt`

Data sample:

```
1234567890;you are my best friend
```

I just want to remove all things which start with ; and replace it in below sample data.

Want output like that:

```
1234567890,1234567
```

The output come with first ten letter comma filename without extension.

Is anyone best in this batch coding please help me in this.

Comment: So you have a file, and want to replace things in the file? This is unclear as I am not able to see if you have multiple lines in the file with the format, or are they only comma separated and semicolon delimited. Please show REAL sample data.

Comment: show your code, so we can enhance it.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `setlocal` on the top of batch file (under your first line)

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Use `forfiles` to get the file name without extension, then send all output into a temp file:

```
forfiles /m 1234567.txt /c "cmd.exe /c echo @fname">temp.txt
```

Use `for` to get the file name:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (temp.txt) do set filename=%%a
```

Make sure to remove `"` in the file name!

```
set filename=%filename:"=%
```

Now use `for` loop again to loop in every line in a file, then print a new line into other file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (1234567.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  set firsttenchars=!line:~0,10!
  rem The above line is used to get first 10 lines (start from char 0)
  set newline=!firsttenchars!,%filename%
  echo !newline!>>temp1.txt
)
```

The last thing is remove the old file then rename `temp1.txt` into `1234567.txt`:

```
del 1234567.txt>nul
ren temp1.txt 1234567.txt
```

Now you just only put all codes together into 1 file and you'll get the result like this:

```
1234567890,1234567
```

Comment: to remove surrounding quotes, better use `set filename=%%~a`